# Open a semicolon seperated file in MS Excel, after I call Workbook.Save() via C# Addin the semicolons will be replaced with comma

Tags: excel, csv, office-interop, excel-addins

I've got a strange behavior in MS Excel 2013 when I develop a C# Addin.
My customer open a CSV file with semicolon delimiters.

Now he can click one of my Addin buttons. One of the buttons will call "Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()" to save changes to file.

After this call MS Excel will replace all semicolons with comma!
If found no solution in Excel API to resolve this bug.

When I save the file via MS Excels blue disc, no replace will be made.

Why?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

--
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your standard format for CSV-files is with semicolons, you can try

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="text.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True
```

local:=True will use whatever delimeter is used normally in your environment.

If that does not work, you can try to create the csv-file with vba directly

Adapt the following code to your needs (found at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/134185-xlcsv-%3D-comma-save-csv-%3D-semicolon-delimited.html#post1724209)

```
Sub CreateCSV()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim sOutput As String
    Dim sFname As String, lFnum As Long

    'Open a text file to write
    sFname = "C:\MyCsv.csv"
    lFnum = FreeFile

    Open sFname For Output As lFnum
    'Loop through the rows'
        For Each rRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        'Loop through the cells in the rows'
        For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
            sOutput = sOutput & rCell.Value & ";"
        Next rCell
         'remove the last comma'
        sOutput = Left(sOutput, Len(sOutput) - 1)

        'write to the file and reinitialize the variables'
        Print #lFnum, sOutput
        sOutput = ""
     Next rRow

    'Close the file'
    Close lFnum

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.
But creating the CSV file in code is not a option. The user open an existing file ,change it and click our addin button. If he opened a XLSX file, there is also no problem to save changes with Excel workbook.Save() command....

Comment: @Sukram But if the user clicks a butten, there is no difference between just calling "Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()" or using my longer code to save the opened CSV. Just replace the dummy-name in "SaveAs" with ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".csv"

Comment: Of course it's a solution. But is there no other way to solve this problem? Why native Excel API Workbook.Save() replace the semicolons?

Comment: I think it is because native Excel (the VBA part) is designed for an "english" environment -  and that uses commas in CSV (comma separated values) files. If you want to enter a formula in vba, you would have to use commas instead of semicolons as well

Comment: It is possible to change VBA language?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not. Same goes for the ".save" method, it uses commas by design if saving csv-files. No way to change this.